# Using IF statement to check if temporary table has rows in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I use an IF statement in my stored procedure to check if my temporary table has rows?

I want to check if #TempDataTable has rows then I would do either of the two statements, insert or update depending on the output.

I did the following:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #TempDataTable 
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM BranchNameTable BT 
         LEFT JOIN BranchLocationActivate BLA ON BT.loc_id = BLA.loc_id 
         WHERE BT.Branchloc = 1;) as Q

    if(//TempDataTable has 0 rows)

       INSERT INTO BranchLocationActivate 
       VALUES(//my values)

    ELSE

       UPDATE BranchLocationActivate 
       SET //My values where //my values
END
```

How do I put it after my select statement in my procedure??

Comment: What you are attempting doesn't make sense.  The only way the temp table could be empty is if BranchNameTable is empty.  Yet, you then say if that's the case, add records to BranchLocationActivate.

Comment: Do you use the temp table for anything outside of that IF statement?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use `not exists`:

```
if (not exists (select 1 from #tempdataatable))
```

Comment: +1 which would be significantly more efficient and faster than using a `COUNT(*) > 0` which can get very slow on a large temp table ....

Comment: When using this kind of  exists select it's better to `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM` this way execution stops after the first row, `SELECT 1 FROM` will give you a 1 from every row, not too bad a difference, but faster is better.

Comment: @Andrew . . . Are you aware of what `not exists` and `exists` do?  It is called a semi-join and that is how a semi-join is implemented.

Comment: I am aware Gordon, just like I am aware that `NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #temptable)` is more efficient than `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #temptable)` while giving the same end result. I have seen timing on both.

Comment: @Andrew . . . Can you reference the timings?  Everything I have seen says that they have the same execution plans.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that there are not any SQL statements between `SELECT * INTO #TempDataTable` and `if(//TempDataTable has 0 rows)` then you don't even need the temp table in the first place. Instead you should simplify the test to be just:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM BranchNameTable BT
                LEFT JOIN BranchLocationActivate BLA
                       ON BT.loc_id = BLA.loc_id
                WHERE BT.Branchloc = 1
              )
   )
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO BranchLocationActivate VALUES(//my values)
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE BranchLocationActivate SET //My values where //my values
END;
```

If there are statements between those parts that make use of the temp table, then you can simplify by using the information SQL Server already gives you after the DML statement via the `@@ROWCOUNT` variable:

```
DECLARE @RowsInserted INT;

SELECT *
INTO #TempDataTable
FROM BranchNameTable BT
LEFT JOIN BranchLocationActivate BLA
       ON BT.loc_id = BLA.loc_id
WHERE BT.Branchloc = 1;

SET @RowsInserted = @@ROWCOUNT;

-- other statements

IF (@RowsInserted = 0)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO BranchLocationActivate VALUES(//my values)
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE BranchLocationActivate SET //My values where //my values
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either proceed with the solution mentioned by Gordon Linoff above, or if the the number of rows might help / a simpler way would be the below;

```
DECLARE @Count AS INT
Select @Count = count (*) from #tempdataatable

If @Count = 0 
BEGIN
    ...
ELSE
    ...
END
```